# Read XML block in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file like below which contain multiple xml. I want to fetch `<Sacd>` content.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sacd>
    <Acdpktg> <Acdpktg/>
</Sacd>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sacd>
    <Acdpktg/>
</Sacd>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sacd>
    <AcdpktG>
        <Result Value="0"/>
        <Packet Value="Dnd"/>
        <Invoke Value="abc"/>
    </AcdpktG>
</Sacd>
```

How do I extract the value inside Sacd tag?

Comment: You tagged this elementtree; did you try using that? What happened? Give a [mre]. Also that seems like multiple XML documents jammed together.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting i expect Result, Packet and Invoke value from each xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your xml is problematic in several respects. First, it contains multiple xml files within in - not a good idea; they have to be split into separate xml files. Second, the first `<Acdpktg> <Acdpktg/>` tag pair is invalid; it should be `<Acdpktg> </Acdpktg>`.

But once it's all fixed, you can get your expected output. So:

```
from lxml import etree
big = """[your xml above,fixed]"""

smalls = big.replace('<?xml','xxx<?xml').split('xxx')[1:] #split it into small xml files

for small in smalls:
    xml = bytes(bytearray(small, encoding='utf-8')) #either this, or remove the xml declarations from each small file
    doc = etree.XML(xml)
    for value in doc.xpath('.//AcdpktG//*/@Value'):     
            print(value)
```

Output:

```
0
Dnd
abc
```

Or, a bit fancier output can be obtained by changing the inner `for` loop a bit:

```
for value in doc.xpath('.//AcdpktG//*'):     
            print(value.tag, value.xpath('./@Value')[0])
```

Output:

```
Result 0
Packet Dnd
Invoke abc
```